# How sort out issue in Python function for add two polynomials

Tags: python-3.x

Each term of the polynomial can be represented as a pair of integers (coefficient,exponent)

```
  def addpoly(p1,p2):
    p1=p1+p2
    d=dict(p1)
    dvalue=list(set(d.values()))
    dkey=list(d.keys())
    result={}
    for n in dvalue:
      result[n] = 0
      for m in dkey:
        if n == d[m]:
          result[n] = result[n] + m

rkey=list(result.keys())
for i in rkey:
  if result[i]==0:
    del result[i]

coff=sorted(list(result.keys()))
coff.reverse()
ans=[(result[k],k) for k in coff]

return(ans)
```

this program is giving correct output, except rest of few cases

For this call `addpoly([(1,1),(-1,0)],[(1,2),(1,1),(1,0)])`does not give correct answer, it output `[]` instead of `[(1,2),(2,1)]`.
What I reason for this when I convert `p1+p2` to dictionary it removes same key items like-- `p1+p2=[(1,1),(-1,0),(1,2),(1,1),(1,0)]`
`dict(p1+p2)` gives `{-1:0,1:0}`.

Answer (score 0):

i tried again & again finally got answer myself to above problem
def addpoly(p1,p2):

```
dp1=dict(map(reversed, p1))
dp2=dict(map(reversed, p2))

d=dict(map(reversed, p1+p2))
dkey=list(d.keys())
result={}
for n in dkey:
    result[n] = 0
    if n in dp1.keys():
        result[n] = result[n] + dp1[n]
    if n in dp2.keys():
        result[n] = result[n] + dp2[n]

rkey=list(result.keys())
for i in rkey:
    if result[i]==0:
        del result[i]

coff=sorted(list(result.keys()))
coff.reverse()
ans=[(result[k],k) for k in coff]

return(ans)
```